# In android how can I fetch all the edittext tag names

Tags: android

In my android project **new_test.xml** contains:--

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/liner" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
         android:tag="user">


    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
         android:tag="name"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/partner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
         android:tag="partner"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
         android:tag="home"/>
      </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to fetch all the tag names of the edittext fields..here is my class file:--

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txt;
String values;

    Context ctx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_test);

       txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.liner);
    for (int i = 0; i<= group.getChildCount();  ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
          if (view instanceof EditText) {
           values = (String) ( ((EditText)view).getTag());
         txt.setText(values);
        }
    }



}
}
```

It should return **user,name,partner,home.**..But it is returning only **"home"**..not all the tagnames..I want to fetch all the tagnames.

I have

```
Formerr  error = new Formerr ();
                    String field= error.getField();
                    String  message= error.getMessage();
```

now I want

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.signup_new_user);
                for (int i = 0; i<= group.getChildCount();  ++i) {
                    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
                      if (view instanceof EditText) {
                       if(field.equals((String) ( ((EditText)view).getTag())))
                    //
                    }
                }
```

here fields is the string..string field will return:--user/name/partner/home(any of them).. when field will match to the tag name..I want to set **String messgae** to that perticular edittext..how can I set that message??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TextView.append(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to show all tags in single TextView:

```
     txt.append(values+"\n");
```

**EDIT:**

> How can I set message to a particular view with that tag name???

Do it as by comparing both strings:

```
View view = group.getChildAt(i);
if (view instanceof EditText) {
  EditText edtText=((EditText)view);
  values = edtText.getTag().toString();
  if(field.equals(values)){
      edtText.setText(message);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Ghostrider: please explain more. what you want.

Comment: Let say I have a string..this string may return user/name/partner/home...I want to compare the string with the tag name.when string equals to tag name then I  want to set a message to that view..

Comment: @Ghostrider: to which String want to compare tags?